# How to Initialize Feathers instance for Jest once

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, feathersjs

I'd like to have just a single instance of feathers "app" when a run jest tests. this is how I import app in every test:

```
const app = require('../../src/app');

describe(`service`, () => {
  it('registered the service', () => {
    const service = app.service('my-service');
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

The problem is that this is creating an instance app and I have over 100 tests, this quickly eats up all of postgres  connections,

my app file exports like this :

```
const app = express(feathers());
app.configure(express.rest()); 
app.configure(objection);
// ... some more configs and bells & whistles
module.exports = app;
```

I thought about opening a socket as a client in the test suite, and instead of importing "app" I open a connection as a client, but thinking of alternatives to that in a test context.

Comment: This has been our experience with Feathers and Jest as well - each Jest test file's app instances are in their own sandbox and do not have a way to be garbage collected or torn down without custom code on our end, and even then it's not perfect depending on what gets held by the global namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are getting there *is* the single instance of the app. There is no initialization overhead for importing the module multiple times.

Comment: is each "app.service" function call opening a new db connection then? how do you handle a big load of parallel tests, they eat up all available connections in the pool rather quickly, but that may be more related to the db adapter than feathers.

Killing knex on afterAll hook works, but I wonder why the service keeps the connection alive by default (or if there's another way to close the service)

Comment: There is only one connection and a big load of parallel tests should just work. As you said, it is probably a database configuration question if it does not.